# Convert selected audio files in vifm using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, vifm

I'm trying to create a command for converting all audio files selected in vifm using ffmpeg. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
command opus ffmpeg -i %f -q 7 %f:s|flac|opus|
```

This has two problems, however.

First, it only works if only one file is selected. If, for example, two are selected, ffmpeg stops with the question, `File 'foo.flac' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]`, where `foo.flac` is the second file.

Second, it only works if the extension of the original files is `flac`. (I used vifm's substitution macro for replacing `flac` with `opus` in the file name in the example.) I don't know how to include other extensions, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trial and error, I've managed to figure it out.

Write a bash script in a separate file, like `ffmpeg-opus.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for file; do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -ab 128k "${file%.*}".opus
done
```

And create a command for it in `vifmrc`:

```
command opus ffmpeg-opus.sh %f
```